# How to avoid native2ascii UTF Encoding BOM Header?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, sdk

I use the native2ascii.exe included in the java sdk to convert ANSI text to UTF8.

```
native2ascii.exe -encoding UTF8
```

The "problem" is: **i need to avoid the auto-insert of the "\ufeff" BOM header.**

Is there a simple way of avoiding that? Maybe automatically remove ti afterwards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a won't-fix bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058

Comment: Geez... you'd think they could at least give us a new charset which is exactly the same as UTF-8 but eats the BOM.

Answer (score 1):

As Victor pointed out, this is a no-fix 'feature'.  What I do is to read the first line of text, and if the first character is the BOM then drop it.

```
if (firstLine.charAt(0) == '\uFEFF') { firstLine = firstLine.substring(1); }
```